# Trying to work with deeplearning4j for the first time but it does not work

Tags: maven, deeplearning4j

I try to follow the quick start guide on deeplearning4j, deeplearning4j.org/quickstart. However, when I try to run "mvn clean install", it give me the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
5.1:compile (default-compile) on project dl4j-examples: Compilation failure: Com
pilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/dl4j-examples/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/example
s/feedforward/classification/DetectGender/PredictGenderTest.java:[8,55] package
org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.messages does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/dl4j-examples/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/example
s/feedforward/classification/DetectGender/PredictGenderTest.java:[9,37] package
org.canova.api.records.reader does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/dl4j-examples/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/example
s/feedforward/classification/DetectGender/PredictGenderTest.java:[10,42] package
 org.canova.api.records.reader.impl does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/dl4j-examples/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/example
s/feedforward/classification/DetectGender/PredictGenderTest.java:[11,28] package
 org.canova.api.split does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/dl4j-examples/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/example
s/feedforward/classification/DetectGender/PredictGenderTest.java:[12,42] package
 org.deeplearning4j.datasets.canova does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/dl4j-examples/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/example
s/feedforward/classification/DetectGender/GenderRecordReader.java:[19,34] packag
e jdk.internal.util.xml.impl does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/dl4j-examples/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/example
s/feedforward/classification/DetectGender/GenderRecordReader.java:[20,56] packag
e org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.core.util does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/dl4j-examples/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/example
s/feedforward/classification/DetectGender/GenderRecordReader.java:[21,30] packag
e org.apache.lucene.util does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :dl4j-examples
```

I also changed java version tag inside pom.xml from 1.7 to 1.8. I also use window 7 64 bit.

Comment: Can you post what were exactly the steps you did?

Comment: first I clone it by "git clone https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples.git". Then, I enter "cd dl4j-examples/". Then I use "mvn clean install". It is exactly like in the quickstart.

Comment: This has been fixed. Thanks! Please do another pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed. Please reclone your the examples.